# How can I transfer a grayscale Image to depth Image

Tags: python, image, matlab, image-processing

My question here is I got a Grayscale Image which the grayscale stands for the depth information, so how can I transfer this grayscale information go back to depth information? Than kyou.

it's rgb mode right now, but each pixel represent a gray color with different level

Comment: RGB mode and gray scale are different things. What exactly do you have for each pixel? What is the dimension?

Comment: each pixel on grayscale is like [80 80 80](it's gray color in RGB), because of the color represent the depth(iPhone's depth camera demo, generate a grayscale picture that stands for depth information), and I want ot get this depth information, Thank you.

Comment: So, if it's grey, then R=G=B, correct? So, just discard Green and Blue (as they are just useless duplicates), and call the Red channel the depth and your job is done.